# move topsearch to content div

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i want to move topsearch div to content div i don't know how to move it even i did change in homepage file `

```
                    <div class="shopdeal"></div>
                    <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms') : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('top-seller')->toHtml() ?>
                    <?php  else:?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="main-inner-wraper">
            <div class="header_search_div">
        <div class="search_left">
        </div>
        <div class="search_content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>
         <div class="search_right">
        </div>
    </div>
                <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-main col-full"> 

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div><!--main col- end-->
            </div><!--main-inner-wraper end-->`
```

and i did change in page.xml also but still no success, anyone suggest me how to do this [please refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdJvN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using css only.  I am using RWD theme, just changed the right and top value of class like

```
#header-search {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 45px;
width: 35%;
height: 50px;
padding: 0px;
right: 60%;
```

}

and gave padding to ol ul of menu,it worked.

Comment: Hey @Shrikant, first of all thanks for suggestion i did that but due to this search stops working so i call <reference name="top">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference> code in catalogsearch.xml file and edit form.mini.phtml file according to my requirement